# Can I run ng build command couple of times?

Tags: angular, angular5, web-deployment

I'am a newbie in Angular. Can I run ng build command couple of times? What will happen? Dist folder will update the code?

Thank you.

Comment: What is stopping you from trying it on your own and seeing what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and run it as many times as you want. After every run the dist folder would be updated if you made changes otherwise it would remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no changes in your files, no matter how many times you use `ng build` command, it will return same hash number (eg: Hash: 70022455d59a3a1c3fb7
) and browsers are also smart enough that they update if they find different Hash number in cashe-busting.

So, no need of multiple times (if there are no changes from previous build).

If you try multiple times, it again looks for is there any chnages occured from previous build or not.

if there are changes, it will return same Hash in the dist otherwise update the dist with new Hash build .